# regex - append after first match

Tags: linux, awk, sed, text-processing

Say I have the following kind of file:

```
a a c
b b c
c c c
d d c
e e c
a a c
b b c
c c c
d d c
e e c
```

How do I end up with:

```
a a c
b b c
c c c
—————
d d c
e e c
a a c
b b c
c c c
d d c
e e c
```

...without just adding the `em dashes` after the 3rd line (first line with `c c c`).

Comment: What precisely do you mean? To insert the dashes only after the first occurrence of `c c c` and not subsequent ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This awk will work:

```
awk '1; !flag && /c c c/ { flag = 1; print "—————" }' filename
```

That is:

```
1                   # first, print every line (1 meaning true here, so the
                    # default action -- printing -- is performed on all
                    # lines)
!flag && /c c c/ {  # if the flag is not yet set and the line we just printed
                    # matches the pattern:
  flag = 1          # set the flag
  print "—————"     # print the dashes.
}
```

Alternatively with sed (although I recommend using the awk solution):

```
sed -n 'p; /c c c/ { x; /^$/ { s//—————/; p }; x }' filename
```

This is a bit more complex. Knowing that the hold buffer is empty in the beginning:

```
p             # print the line
/c c c/ {     # if it matches the pattern:
  x           # exchange hold buffer and pattern space
  /^$/ {      # if the pattern space (that used to be the hold buffer) is
              # empty:
    s//—————/ # replace it with the dashes
    p         # print them
  }
  x           # and exchange again. The hold buffer is now no longer empty,
              # and the dash block will not be executed again.
}
```

Comment: Probably is `GNU sed` only but this should work too `sed '0,/c c c/s//&\n-----/' file`. ++ none the less.

Comment: @jaypalsingh it does work. Do you want to make that a separate answer, or should I just accept Wintermute's?

Comment: @jaypalsingh: Ah, one caveat: It works only if `c c c` is at the end of the matched line. This is not a problem with line patterns (i.e., `^c c c$`), but if the pattern should match only a part of the line and the dashes should still be inserted after the line, you'll need `sed '0,/c c c/ { // s/.*/&\n-----/ }'` or so. Still, the range idea is nice.

Comment: @Det Please go ahead and accept this answer. Wintermute, true.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/c c c/!b
s/$/\
-----/
# Using buffer
:cycle
N
$!b cycle' YourFile
```

- until first  `c c c`, just print the line
- add a line on line (so at 1st ccc)
- load a line in buffer (and no print)
- cycle the load until last line
- last line print the whole (by exiting the loop, not the action like a new `N` cycle will do)

or alternative for huge file by using a small buffering

```
# without big buffer
:cycle
n
s/.*\n//
$!b cycle' YourFile
```

- print 1st line and load a new one
- remove first line
- cycle if not the end